# Обработчик на динамический audio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим я создаю динамически audio элемент на странице. Для всех audio, которые были на страницы событие play работает, но для вновь созданного - нет. Понятно почему, но как это исправить ? (Если можно, конечно)

Пытаюсь что-то подобное, но не работает.

```
$(document).on('play','audio',function(){ .. })
```

```js
$('button.add').click(function(){

  $('div.append').append('<audio controls><source src="https://cdn.drivemusic.me/dl/online/pG3iszQQHYzthoyGyirc7Q/1637257810/download_music/2013/08/alex-hepburn-under-radio-version.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>')
})

$(function(){
  $('audio').on('play',function(){
        $('audio').addClass('stoped');
        $(this).removeClass('stoped').addClass('playing');
         $('.stoped').each(function() {
             $(this)[0].pause();
            $(this)[0].currentTime = 0;
        })
  
  })

})

// Такая конструкция, которая могла бы помочь с динамическими элементами - не работает.
$(document).on('load','audio',function(){
console.log('da');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Заранее добавленные audio. Выключаются, если "один из" играет.</p>
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://cdn.drivemusic.me/dl/online/pG3iszQQHYzthoyGyirc7Q/1637257810/download_music/2013/08/alex-hepburn-under-radio-version.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://cdn.drivemusic.me/dl/online/pG3iszQQHYzthoyGyirc7Q/1637257810/download_music/2013/08/alex-hepburn-under-radio-version.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<p>Динамически созданные audio не будут выключать остальные, если начать их проигрывать, но заранее добавленные спокойно выключают новые</p>
<div class="append"></div>
<button class="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Добавь [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Добавил

Comment: забавно.... в теле вопроса ты пишешь, что у тебя не работает `$(document).on('play','audio'`  а в коде у тебя `$('audio').on('play'`

Comment: как раз первый вариант должен быть рабочим, а в коде - понятно что не работает

Comment: Потому, что на момент создания страницы элементы `audio`, что будут добавлены потом на ней отсутствуют и обработчик `js` на них естественно не может быть навешан.  Просто вызывайте `$('audio').on('play'...` при каждом добавлении нового `audio`, не забыв вначале снять его с тех что уже существуют либо вместо `audio` используйте конкретный селектор добавленного элемента.

Comment: @phpBear зачем так сложно, если можно использовать делегирование событий? Которое, между прочим, автор уже описал в теле вопроса, но в коде его не реализовал почему-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну он же написал что `$(document).on()` у него не работает, поэтому я ему и предложил другой вариант. А так-то конечно первое что в голову приходит навешать сразу на `body`

Comment: @phpBear Я знаю, что так можно вызывать `$('audio').on('play'..)`, но неужели нет более "элегантного" решения ?

Comment: Забавно, но кажется jquery не умеет в делегирование для audio и video. Потому что у этих тегов отключено всплытие (bubbling)....... А вот `addEventListener`  умеет   https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630384/6104996   .....потому что можно всплытие включить....... поэтому тут выбора три: 1) либо смешивать нативный js с jq. но решить проблему красивее 2) либо делать обёртку для jq как в примере выше 3) либо действительно при клике везде снимать события и вешать заново

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Алексей Шиманский и phpBear.

Наговнокодил такой смешанный вариант

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == 'AUDIO'){
        $('audio').addClass('stoped');
        $(e.target).removeClass('stoped').addClass('playing');
        $('.stoped').each(function() {
            $(this)[0].pause();
            $(this)[0].currentTime = 0;
        })
    }
}, true);
```

Также нашел инфу на eng версии, как можно использовать `$(document).on('play'..`

Шаг 1

```
$.createEventCapturing = (function () {
    var special = $.event.special;
    return function (names) {
        if (!document.addEventListener) {
            return;
        }
        if (typeof names == 'string') {
            names = [names];
        }
        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            var handler = function (e) {
                e = $.event.fix(e);

                return $.event.dispatch.call(this, e);
            };
            special[name] = special[name] || {};
            if (special[name].setup || special[name].teardown) {
                return;
            }
            $.extend(special[name], {
                setup: function () {
                    this.addEventListener(name, handler, true);
                },
                teardown: function () {
                    this.removeEventListener(name, handler, true);
                }
            });
        });
    };
})();
```

Шаг 2

```
$.createEventCapturing(['play', 'pause']);

$(document).on('play', function(e){
    
});
```

Источник - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble

И то и то работает как надо

Comment: Ну что уж сразу `наговнокодил`... Главное что работает :) А улучшать код будете по мере накопления опыта :)